# tensorflow attributeerror moddule has no attribute per_image_standardization

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to go through the tutorial on convolutional neural nets using cifar10.  The cnn is being built (cifar10.py) but when I try to run cifar10_train.py I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cifar10_train.py", line 115, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "cifar10_train.py", line 111, in main
    train()
  File "cifar10_train.py", line 58, in train
    images, labels = cifar10.distorted_inputs()
  File "/home/brennus/workspace/python/cifar/cifar10.py", line 141, in distorted_inputs
    batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
  File "/home/brennus/workspace/python/cifar/cifar10_input.py", line 177, in distorted_inputs
    float_image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(distorted_image)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'per_image_standardization'
```

According to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/image.md, there is indeed a per_image_standardization attribute but it looks like my tensorflow doesn't have it.  I'm not sure what version I have and not sure where to find it, but I built it from source from the repository so I imagine it's the current one.

I can't find anyone else who is having this problem so I'm stymied.  Maybe I have to write my own?

Comment: This looks like a build issue rather than something that was removed. The op [exists at head](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py#L704), and in `docker run -it  gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:1.0.0-rc1 ipython` as `tf.image.per_image_standardization`. Did you build a pip package from source and then install that?

Comment: have the same problem using tf11

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled tensorflow and solved the problem.  Thanks, all!